# How can I convert rtf to txt files on Kali Linux by command-line?

Tags: linux, converters

I have 30 rtf files that I need to convert all of them to txt. Is there any script can I run it on command line and do Multiple-Files convert

I’m using Kali Linux 2020.2 ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem and tested the recommended programs [here](https://superuser.com/questions/243084/rtf-to-txt-on-unix).

Of those, I found `unoconv` to work the best. A one-liner to convert everything in one directory is:

```
for rtf in rtf/*.rtf; do unoconv -f txt $rtf;done
```

Please note that unoconv adds a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) mark at the beginning of each .txt file (at least for my rtf files), so if your future processing can't handle that you should strip it.

Comment: My unoconv v. 0.6 adds a BOM with `-f txt`, but it doesn't when using `-f text` instead.